# Why set is not allowed duplicate value, which kind of mechanism used behind them?

Tags: java

I am new to java, i know ***set is not allowed duplicate value*** but i don't know ***why set is not allowed duplicate value***, Actually i am doing practically,

Declared one set and add duplicate value but no kind of error is occurring, no compile time error, no run time. **why?**

Comment: @norlesh: How do you know "i am know for java" was meant to be "I am new to java"? It's best not to speculate when editing.

Comment: what would you suggest  is an alternate interpretation?

Comment: @norlesh: I suggest not guessing. Unless one is sure, one should leave the OP's text alone in hopes someone else understands it. I've seen a number of clearly-wrong guesses, where the editor basically ended up (inadvertently) vandalizing the question. (As well as, of course, a *lot* of cases where edits have improved/corrected questions.)

Comment: {1,2,3} Union {2} = {1,2,3}, straight math.

Comment: It doesn't say it is an error anywhere. Duplicates are ignored.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I feel there would have to be an element of guess in every and any edit done on SO by a 2nd party and if that weren't acceptable then I see no reason to allow 2nd party edits.

Comment: @norlesh: Well, we just disagree then. Happens all the time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The meaning of "sets do not allow duplicate values" is that when you add a duplicate to a set, the duplicate is ignored, and the set remains unchanged. This does not lead to compile or runtime errors: duplicates are silently ignored.

You can tell that a value is a duplicate by checking the result of `add`, like this:

```
Set<String> testSet = new HashSet<String>();
boolean first = testSet.add("hello");
System.out.println(first);             // Prints "true"
boolean second = testSet.add("hello");
System.out.println(second);            // Prints "false"
```

Answer (score 20):

Internally **SET** store element using **HASHTABLE** ...**HASHTABLE** is a structure of Key value pairs..Here what the values passed by the **SET** is treated as Keys of **HASHTABLE** Internally. keys are unique cannot be duplicated. That is the reason if you pass any duplicate value it return false and does not added to the **SET** ...

If the adding element return true it will added into **SET**...Else it return False, that why it won't give any compilation or runtime error and it wont be added to **SET**

Comment: So, Set internally works HASH TABLE, why Set is not synchronized?

Comment: @satzkmr [Hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is a general term, it doesn't necessarily relate to `java.util.Hashtable`.

Answer (score 6):

Set is not allowed to store duplicated values by definition. If you need duplicated values, use a List. As specified on the documentation of the interface, when you try to add a duplicated value, the method `add` returns false, not an Exception.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Answer (score 4):

### **Set (Oracle Documentation)**

A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

### **Set (Methematics) - Quoting from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29)**

In mathematics, a set is a collection of distinct objects, considered as an object in its own right.

### **Add Method**

According to the documentation of the interface, if the element does not exist it is added. Otherwise, nothing changes.

**boolean   add(E e):**

Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present (optional operation).  If this set already contains the element, the call **leaves the set unchanged and returns false**.

### **Example Implementation Code: HashSet**

```
 /**
     * Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present.
     * More formally, adds the specified element <tt>e</tt> to this set if
     * this set contains no element <tt>e2</tt> such that
     * <tt>(e==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;e2==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;e.equals(e2))</tt>.
     * If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set
     * unchanged and returns <tt>false</tt>.
     *
     * @param e element to be added to this set
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if this set did not already contain the specified
     * element
     */
    public boolean add(E e) {
        return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

So it is well known fact that Set is not allowing duplicate or equal objects but equality of the objects will be taken care by the programmer by giving the desired implementation of equals() and hashCode() methods.
if we are not implementing these two methods set will even allow duplicates also.
In hash based collections in java, first hashCode() method called and then equals() method called if required to check the equality of the objects. 
,so bottom line is Set is using Map functionality internally and set values are inserted as keys inside this map internally and map is not allowing duplicate keys,
You can also check the HashSet.java class from Java API where you can find similar map which is actually doing all the things.

Here is small code sample:

```
class Employee {
    private static int equalsCounter;
    private static int hashCodeCounter;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    public Employee(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        hashCodeCounter++;
        System.out.println("hashCode() invoked : "+hashCodeCounter+" time");
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + age;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        equalsCounter++;
        System.out.println("equals() invoked: "+equalsCounter+" time");
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (age != other.age)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Employee> mySet  = new HashSet<Employee>();
        Employee e1 = new Employee("aaa", 30);
        Employee e2 = new Employee("aaa", 30);
        Employee e3 = new Employee("aaa", 30);
        mySet.add(e1); // HashCode() called and equals() not called
        mySet.add(e2);// HashCode() called and equals() also called
        mySet.add(e3);// HashCode() called and equals() also called
        System.out.println(mySet.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition of above answers, here is why set does not allow duplicate elements:

When you call add(E e), method of set, it internally call put(E, e) method of HashMap which looks something like this :

```
 public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Hence, the element you are adding to set/HashSet, is internally added to Map as a key. As we need to associate some value with the key in so dummy value(new Object()) PRESENT is passed every time (as Map can contain more than one duplicate values ).

Now if you closely examine the  `return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;` of add(e, E) method. There can be two possibilities :

1. if map.put(k,v) returns null ,then
   `map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;` will return true and element will be added.
2. if map.put(k,v) returns old value for the key ,then
   `map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;` will return false and element will not be added.

Hope this will help in understanding clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to A2A..

When you pass a duplicate element in the add method of set object, It'll return false and doesn't add it to the set as the element is already present.

```
Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>();
set.add("test");
set.add("test");
```

If you look at the implementation of HashSet then it looks like following.

```
public HashSet() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }
```

Means HashSet internally creates an object of HashMap.

```
public boolean add(E e) {
        return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    }
```

If you look at the add method parameter e, then your passed value (test) will be consider as a key in the map and the PRESENT is the dummy object passed as a value.

HashMap put method returns the following

```
 1. null, if the key is unique and added to the map
 2. Old value of the key, if key is duplicate
```

So, when you are adding test element for the first time, HashMap will add the element and return null after that your add method of set will return true. If you add the test element for 2nd time then your HashMap will return Old Value of the Key then in add method of your set will return false as OldValue != null

Hope it'll be helpful..!!

Answer (score 0):

Because that's how sets are defined. An element can only exist once in a set, but that doesn't mean trying to add it a second time should be an error. It's just a no-op. This is fairly clear from the documentation, for instance, for [`Set#add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29):

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present (optional operation). ... If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false. In combination with the restriction on constructors, this ensures that sets never contain duplicate elements.

Among other things, this lets you happily add to sets without worrying, and know that the result will only ever have unique values in it.

> Declared one set and add duplicate value but no any kind of error are occur, no compile time error no run time. Why?

Because it's not an error. But note that you *did* (or could have) received an indication that the value was already present: The `add` method's return value (see link above) tells you: *"`true` if this set did not already contain the specified element"*

Answer (score 0):

"a set is a collection of distinct objects" ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29

When you create a set there can be only unique objects in it by definition. Adding same object twice does not change the set as the element/object is already in the set. This is expected behavior. An example where this behavior is useful is when one wants to find unique elements from a collection of elements (i.e. remove duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, you can get the following:

Adds the specified element e to this set if the set contains no element e2 such that `(e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2))`. If this set already contains the element, duplicate is ignored, leaves the set unchanged and returns false. This ensures that sets never contain duplicate elements.

`boolean add(E e)`: The method returns true if the set did not already contain the specified element.

It throws the following types of exceptions:

**UnsupportedOperationException** - if the add operation is not supported by this set

**ClassCastException** - if the class of the specified element prevents it from being added to this set

**NullPointerException** - if the specified element is null and this set does not permit null elements

**IllegalArgumentException** - if some property of the specified element prevents it from being added to this set