# HashSet internally uses HashMap. In HashMap, If we are trying to put the same key, the previous value is overridden

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, set

But how the HashSet does not allow duplicates?

```
Set hs = new HashSet(); 

// adding elements to hashset 
// using add() method 
boolean b1 = hs.add("Geeks"); 
boolean b2 = hs.add("GeeksforGeeks"); 

// adding duplicate element 
boolean b3 = hs.add("Geeks");
```

Comment: The existing **value** in a `HashMap` is overwritten, but `HashSet` does not use the **value** portion of its backing `HashMap` (it stores a dummy value, like `Boolean.TRUE`).

Comment: The elements you add in a HashSet gets internally stored as the key of a hashmap. Thats why you cannot have duplicate elements in it.

Comment: Could you please provide more information or further explain you question?

Comment: FYI, For the most detailed insight the best would be to read the source code of Hashset class.

Comment: If you're asking _why_ `HashSet` doesn't allow duplicates then the answer is: because that's what defines a set, i.e. no duplicates. If you're actually asking how this is done: as the others already said `HashSet` internally uses `HashMap` with that map's key _set_ representing the `HashSet` (values don't matter in this case).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870879/why-set-is-not-allowed-duplicate-value-which-kind-of-mechanism-used-behind-them